# Sharing ajax data between multiple controllers in angular using service

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have two controllers

```
pqsAppModule.controller('NotificationBoxController',function($scope,items) {
    $scope.list = items.list();
})
```

and

```
pqsAppModule.controller('NotificationController',function($scope,items) {
    $scope.list = items.list();
})
```

I need to create an "items" service that would do an ajax request and return data for any controller which would have it injected. And I want, that the query will be done only once, and items will be shared between all controllers.

```
pqsAppModule.factory('items', function($http) {
    var items = [];
    var itemsService = {};
    $http.get('api/notification').then(function(response){
        items = response.data;
    });

    itemsService.list = function() {
        return items;
    };

    return itemsService;
});
```

But I don't understand why angular makes the request, and receives data, but all items in controllers are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the factory should be defined by different way.

*(I took dummy URL only to load data by async way)*

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="NotificationBoxController">
    <button ng-click="showMe();">press  me</button>
    <pre>NotificationBoxController: {{items.getList()|json}}</pre>
</div>

<div ng-controller="NotificationController">
    <pre>NotificationController: {{items.getList()|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var pqsAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
pqsAppModule.controller('NotificationBoxController',function($scope,items) {
    $scope.items = items;

    $scope.showMe= function(){
     items.query();   
    }
});

pqsAppModule.controller('NotificationController',function($scope,items) {
    $scope.items = items;
});


pqsAppModule.factory('items', function ($http) {

    var current = {};    

    var address = 'Singapore, SG, Singapore, 153 Bukit Batok Street 1';
    var URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&sensor=true';

       var factory = {            
           query: function () {                
                var data = $http({method: 'GET', url:URL}).then(function (result) {
                           current = result.data.results[0];                            
                        }, function (result) {
                            alert("Error: No data returned");
                        });  
            },
            getList: function () {                
               return current;
            }
       }       
        return factory; 
  });
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/1012/)**</kbd>

From this example we call `items.getList()` from HTML for both controllers. But if we want to update the model through the controller, we need a listener like `$watch`

Comment: yes it works, but one more question. I must declare watch inside the service factory?

Comment: no, you don't. Factory is like singleton. has one instance and all controllers use the same service. you can add watch to controller and listen on change in service

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $http.get('api/notification').then(function(response){
        angular.foreach(response.data,function(item) {
            items.push(item);
        });
    });
```

Basically do not create a new array but fill the existing one.