# share and save data from multiple controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't seem to figure out which way to go about this problem:

I got multiple angular controllers, they all need a user-object, which they can manipulate with, and each time it gets manipulated the "new" data needs to be out in the other controllers aswell. At the same time i need to save this user-object in the database for retrievel afterwards (so a auto save function when data is changed on user-object)

But i can't seem to figure out whether i should using a factory or a service to hold this user-object, and how i can get this factory/service to save the user on change via a API.

I read this [Sharing ajax data between multiple controllers in angular using service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512439/sharing-ajax-data-between-multiple-controllers-in-angular-using-service) example where he wants to accomplish some of the same things, but the API part and async automatic saving is really giving me trouble!

Bottom line is, i have multiple controllers which needs a user-object from the serverside. And these controllers manipulates with the same user-object, and after each manipulation(maybe with some debounce), i want to save the object to the database via API.

(first of, i thought of watching the object in the service/factory, but found out i couldn't :( )

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You create a `User` object (either via a service or a factory).
2. You inject that object into any controller that wants to interact with it.
3. You `$watch` that object (from inside the service itself if you consider that functionality to be a core part of the `User` entity) and update the backend when a change is detected (optionally with a debounce).
4. For `$watch`ing something from inside a service, you can inject the `$rootScope` service.
5. Keep in mind that (in a real app) you need to account for errors and corner-cases. E.g. what happens if the user navigates away from the page before the debounce period has passed etc.

<sub>Below is a naive POC implementation. In the real world, you'd probably want to use module (like the ones mentioned by [Mikke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788104/share-and-save-data-from-multiple-controllers-in-angularjs/25789210#answer-25788369)) and wrap yur service around it, in order to save a lot of boilerplate code while interacting with your RESTful data source.</sub>

---

A demo service might look like this:

```
.factory('User', function ($q, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    var apiEndpoint = '/api/user';
    var guest = {
        username: 'Guest',
        email   : null,
        loggedIn: false
    };
    var user = {};

    user.login = function (credentials) {
        user.logout();

        // In real app: Make a login request
        var request = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            user.username = 'ExpertSystem';
            user.email    = 'expert@system';
            user.loggedIn = true;
            request.resolve(user);
        }, 1000);

        return request.promise;
    };

    user.logout = function () {
        // In real app: Make a logout request
        angular.extend(user, guest);
    };

    user.update = function () {
        // In real app: Make a request to update user info
        alert('Updating the backend...');
    };

    var updateTimeout;
    user.updateWithDebounce = function () {
        $timeout.cancel(updateTimeout);
        updateTimeout = $timeout(function () {
            user.update();
        }, 1000);
    };

    $rootScope.$watchCollection(function () {
        return user;
    }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        var shouldUpdate = newValue && newValue.loggedIn &&
                           oldValue && oldValue.loggedIn;
        // Immediate backend update
        //if (shouldUpdate) user.update();

        // Debounced backend update (1 sec debounce)
        if (shouldUpdate) user.updateWithDebounce();
    });

    user.login();

    return user;
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/w4n8gv1h/)**.

Comment: Great example.. After trying to mix it i started all over agian, and  took your code and mixed mine in. And it worked perfectly.
I just gotta get used to the though of my user object in the controllers has both properties and methods on it. 
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Whether to create a service or factory is really a design issue.

You probably want to look at libraries such as [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) or [ThickM](https://github.com/simplicitylabs/angular-thickm), which helps you create services which relate your models to API endpoints for fetching and saving.

Asynchronous automatic saving could be solved either in the service or on controllers.

Disclosure: I'm the author of ThickM.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing data between controllers a service is the way to go. You seem to have a good idea about this already.

For saving the user after each manipulation I don't understand what the issue is. Create a modify user method after which you could do an object comparison. If there is a difference send the PUT request to the api.

Comment: But where should i create this comparison? In my little fantasy would i'd like to do something like this in the controller: 
$scope.user.name.lastName = "Hansen"; (or even a ng-model bind to a input field) 
And then in the service 'catches' the change and saves the data through a factory i suppose. 
But how can the service see that there has been a change? 
i a controller i would $watch, but i can't in the service.

Comment: if the service is injected into your controller you can access it easily. ServiceName.user.name.lastName = 'abc' or maybe even better a user object ServiceName.user.editName({lastName:'abc'}). The object could contain a comparison function which the edit function could call after applying the change

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you always share data between your controllers (and also directives) using a Service/Factory and injecting it on both sides.

After that, just use your promise resolution function to update the service value.

```
app.factory('SharedService', function() {
  return {
    sharedObject: {
      value: '',
      value2: ''
    }
  };
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, SharedService) {
  $scope.model = SharedService.sharedObject;
});

app.directive('myDirective',['SharedService', function(SharedService){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.model = SharedService.sharedObject;
    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="model.value"/></div>'
  }
}]);
```

Here is a plunkr showing how it can be done:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m

Comment: seems legit. 
Though i got a problem that the factory data is fetched async, and it seems that the controllers can't get the fetched data from my factory's $http.get.